# counterexample of reflexive space not hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

We know that *all Hilbert spaces are reflexive*. My problem is to show that the reciproque is not true: But I can't find a counterexample. An idea please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\ell^{p}, L^{p}([0,1])$ with $1 <p <\infty$ are reflexive spaces which are not inner product spaces.